# Как обрезать элемент

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обрезать `div` как на картинке? 
Свойство `border-radius` не подходит, т.к. скругливает, а мне нужна ровная линия

Comment: обрезать то, что черным?

Comment: В принципе не важно, главное чтобы эффект был тот же

Comment: transform: skew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css-треугольники вам в [помощь](http://ktvd.ru/triangles-on-css/)

```css
.black
{
  background-color: black;
    padding: 20px 50px 0;
  width: 400px;
}

.block {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;

  width: 80px;
   }
   .block::before {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
     top: 0;
left: -20px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 40px 20px;
border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
   }
.block::after {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
     top: 0;
right: -20px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 20px 40px 0px;
border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
   }
```

```html
<div class="black"> <div class="block">
   Блок
  </div></div>
```